# First word from each cell in a range

Tags: google-apps-script, split, range, element

Need the first word from each cell in a range that is passed into a custom function.

The logic in the custom function  works when used on a explicitly defined array within the function that was used to test the logic.

The logic to splice  of the first word in from each element in the passed in array fails when used in on a range that's passed in.

Trying to figure out how to use the split method on a range to return just the first word of each element:

```
    /**
* @customfunction
*/
function test()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("B1:I1");
  var array = sheet.getValues();
  var alt_activities_range = array;

  //Map to create a new array (same dimensions new values). Leave only the first word of each array
  //You want to compare the first word of each element from two different arrays
  //use split on array element and return index[0] for comparison

  return Logger.log(alt_activities_range);
  var alt_activities_array = alt_activities_range.map(str => {
    let arr = str.split(' ');
    return arr[0];
  });

  console.log(alt_activities_array);
}
```

[Test Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

Found my neophyte's error. I copied one array into another creating a 2D array and never passed the actual elements as string to the the split function.